# Combobox list not being populated in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I'm working in MVVM WPF. I'm having a listBox included in a popup panel. The popup is displayed, but the listBox is not filled, have no ideea why.The list box is used for filter a column of data. Here is the listBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxPopupContent" ItemsSource="{Binding ClassViewMethod}">
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding ClassName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and the model view:

```
public ObservableCollection<ClassView> ClassViewMethod
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (string cust in ClassViewItems.Select(w => w.ClassName).Distinct().OrderBy(w => w))
            {
                classFilters.Add(new CheckedListItem<string> { Item = cust, IsChecked = true });
            }
            viewSource.Filter += viewSource_Filter;
            viewSource.Source = ClassViewItems;
            return ClassViewItems;
        }
    }

    private void viewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        ClassView cust = (ClassView)e.Item;

        int count = classFilters.Where(w => w.IsChecked).Count(w => w.Item == cust.ClassName);

        if (count == 0)
        {
            e.Accepted = false;
            return;
        }

        e.Accepted = true;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ClassView> ClassViewItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _classView;
        }

        set
        {
            _classView = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ClassViewItems");

        }
```

DataContext is set like(in app.xaml):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainWindowViewModel" />
</Application.Resources>
```

and in MainWindow.xaml:

```
 DataContext="{StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}"
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about this code. MainWindowViewModel is the view model for the MainWindow. So I would expect that in the constructor of MainWindow (of by XAML, whatever) you create and attach the viewmodel by assigning it to the Windows' DataContext property. But here, your MainWindowViewModel, has its own DataContext property. And you are assigning the controls (lstClassName, grdData, ...) as if it were your MainWindowViewModel's properties. It looks like your MainWindow and MainWindowViewModel is the same class.

Comment: Can we see `Popup` part of xaml?

Comment: This isn't MVVM at all. Assigning UI element properties in a view model makes no sense. That said, you don't seem to set or bind the ItemsSource of listBoxPopupContent anywhere.

Comment: listBoxPopupContent.ItemsSource = viewSource.View; ??

Comment: `ListBox` will be EMPTY because you are not assigning it's `ItemsSource` anywhere. As far as the ListBox goes.

Comment: @Sjips, I've edited my question now. The popup list is filled, but the filtering doesn't go at all. I don t know why I am not able to put "Content="{Binding Item}" " in the view.. if I write this the popup is empty, there are no class names

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify that the page's DataContext is being set to the active instance of the VM.

Secondly the VM needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to signal that the item stored at `ClassViewMethod` has a changed item.

Making the target an `ObservableCollection` does not affect that dynamic. So when the page should view the collection a call to notify event is signaled and the control loads the data. I don't see that notify event in your example hence one out of two possible failure points.

---

I demonstrate all that on my blog post [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've implemented the notify property and DataContext was already set. is still doesn't working.. the list is fill and that s all. I've edited my question, maybe you have an idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Nica Where is the `NotifyPropertyChanged("ClassViewMethod")` done? By your example it never gets done and without that event, the combobox won't load the data via reflection.